# the inputs must be registered and then magnitude must be taken of 2's complement numbers only

Tags: verilog

```
module multiplier(//global inputs
          i_clk,i_rst,
          //outputs
          o_product,o_done,
          //input
          i_multiplicant,i_multiplier,i_start
          );

   //parameter declarations
   parameter MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH =5;       //width for multiplicant
   parameter MULTIPLIER_WIDTH =5;        //width for multiplier
   parameter TWOSCOMP=0;                  //'1'=signed multiplication and '0'=unsigned multiplication
   parameter PRODUCT_WIDTH =(MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH+MULTIPLIER_WIDTH);   //width of the product  
   parameter NPOWER = 6;                           //multiplier width<=2**NPOWER
   parameter NULL_VECTOR_S = 32'h00000000;       //used to fill the upper part of product register with zero at the begining of multiplication
   parameter S0= 2'd0;
   parameter S1= 2'd1;
   parameter S2= 2'd2;  


   //global inputs
   input i_clk;
   input i_rst;

   //outputs
   output reg [PRODUCT_WIDTH-1:0] o_product;
   output             o_done;

   //input           
   input [MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1:0] i_multiplicant;
   input [MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1:0]   i_multiplier;
   input              i_start;      //indicates start of multiplication

   // reg and wire declarations
   reg                o_done; 
   reg                sign_i;      //sign product
   reg [PRODUCT_WIDTH-1:0]    product_i; 
   reg [PRODUCT_WIDTH-1:0]    product_ii;  
   reg [NPOWER-1:0]           count_i;    
   reg [MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1:0]   multiplicant_i;
   reg [MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1:0]     multiplier_i;
   reg                add_i;
   reg                shr_i;
   reg [1:0]              state=2'b00;
   reg [1:0]              nextstate=2'b00;

   //correcting the bits for signed multiplication
```

/*this is the place were i am trying to make the inputs registered..i dont get any error but the FSM is giving problem.Addording to me the unsigned number's result should be available 2 cycles earlier than signed product.The FSM should start at different instsnces and o_done should be generated differently for unsigned and unsigned numbers. but i dont kow how to do it. can some one help me  */

```
     generate
      if(TWOSCOMP==1) 
    always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)
      begin  
         if(i_rst)begin 
              multiplicant_i<=0;
              multiplier_i<=0;
             end  else begin
             $display("Testing signed numbers");
                 sign_i<= i_multiplicant[MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1] ^ i_multiplier[MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1]; 
             multiplicant_i=rectify_multcnd(i_multiplicant,TWOSCOMP); 
         multiplier_i=rectify_mulplr(i_multiplier,TWOSCOMP);
     end 
     end 
   endgenerate 
  generate
      if(TWOSCOMP==0)
    always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)
      begin    
          if(i_rst==1) begin 
              multiplicant_i<=0;
              multiplier_i<=0;
              end else begin  
       $display("Testing unsigned numbers"); 
         multiplicant_i<=i_multiplicant;
         multiplier_i<=i_multiplier;
     end 
      end 
   endgenerate   


   //functionn to correct multiplicant bits   
   function [MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1:0]rectify_multcnd;    
      input [MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1:0]multiplicant;
      reg [MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1:0]  rec_v;
      input                 twoc;
      begin
     if((multiplicant[MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1] & twoc)==1)
       rec_v=~(multiplicant);
     else
       rec_v=multiplicant;
     rectify_multcnd=(rec_v+(multiplicant[MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1] & twoc));
      end
   endfunction
   //function to correct multipier bits            
   function [MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1:0]rectify_mulplr;   
      input [MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1:0]multiplier;
      reg [MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1:0]  rec_v;
      input               twoc;
      begin
     if((multiplier[MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1] & twoc)==1)
       rec_v=~(multiplier);
     else
       rec_v=multiplier;
     rectify_mulplr=(rec_v+(multiplier[MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1] & twoc));
      end
   endfunction     

   //start of multiplication  
   always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst) 
     begin
    if(i_rst==1)
      product_i<=18'd0;
    else begin 
       if(i_start==1) begin 
          product_i <= {NULL_VECTOR_S[MULTIPLICANT_WIDTH-1:0], multiplier_i}; 
       end  else if (add_i==1)
         product_i<= {{1'b0, product_i[PRODUCT_WIDTH-1:MULTIPLIER_WIDTH]} + {1'b0,multiplicant_i}, product_i[MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1:1]};
       else if (shr_i==1)
         product_i<= {1'b0 , product_i[PRODUCT_WIDTH-1:1]};
    end 
     end // always@ (posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst or posedge i_start)

   //always block to transverse through the states   
   always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)
     begin
    if(i_rst==1)begin
       state<=S0;
       count_i<=0;
    end else begin
       state<=nextstate;
       if(state==S1) begin
          count_i<=count_i-1;   
       end 
       else if (state==S0)  begin 
          count_i<=(MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1);
       end
    end 
     end // always@ (posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)

   always@(state,i_start,product_i,count_i)
     begin                                
        case (state) 
          S0 :begin 
             add_i <= 0;
             shr_i <= 0;
             o_done <= 0;                                           
             if  (i_start==1) 
               nextstate <= S1; 
             else 
               nextstate <= S1;
      end 
          S1:begin
             o_done  <= 0;                                           
             add_i <= product_i[0]; 
             shr_i <= ~product_i[0];
             if (count_i==NULL_VECTOR_S [(MULTIPLIER_WIDTH-1):0])
               nextstate <= S2 ; 
             else 
               nextstate <= S1;      
          end              
          S2 :begin  
             o_done  <= 1;                                           
             add_i <= 0;
             shr_i <= 0;
             nextstate <= S0;
      end 
      default:begin
             o_done  <= 0;                                           
             add_i <= 0;
             shr_i <= 0;                                           
             nextstate <= S0;
          end
    endcase // case (state)     
     end // always@ (state,i_start,product_i,count_i) 

   generate
      if(TWOSCOMP==1)
    always@(state,i_start,product_i,count_i)
      begin 
         if(sign_i ==1)
           product_ii<=((~(product_i)) + 1); 
         else
           product_ii<=product_i;
      end  
   endgenerate 

   generate
      if(TWOSCOMP==0)
    always@(state,i_start,product_i,count_i)
      begin 
         o_product<=product_i;
      end
   endgenerate 

   always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)
     begin
    if(i_rst==1)
      o_product<=0;
    else if(TWOSCOMP==1)begin 
       o_product<=product_ii;
    end  
     end     
endmodule // multiplier
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by register inputs, do you want to put them through a flip-flop?

Comment: Good questions show the minimum code to recreate the problem, the generates you have used to deal with TWOCOMP add complication. that adds to our time to read and understand the problem. Help us to help you.

Comment: yes i want put them through flip flop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To buffer or register an input then take the magnitude of a 2's complement number:

```
module fubar(
  input                     clk,
  input                     rst_n,
  input                     twocomp, //Could be param
  input       signed [31:0] a,
  output reg         [31:0] abs_a
);
  //Buffer input
  reg signed [31:0] a_buf;
  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
    if (~rst_n) begin
      a_buf <= 'b0;
    end
    else begin
      a_buf <= a;
    end
  end

  //If Two Comp mode enabled and input was negative
  // invert (absolute value)
  always @* begin
    if ((twocomp == 1'b1) && (a_buf[31] == 1'b1)) begin
      abs_a = -a_buf;
    end
    else begin
      abs_a = a;
    end
  end

endmodule
```